# Play framework 2.2.1 app terminates with a strange Killed message

Tags: linux, scala, playframework

I am running a play app written in Scala working with PostgreSQL via Slick in development mode. New Relic agents are installed both on play and on the server. The system is an Ubuntu 12.04.3 x64 on a VPS. It has only 1 GiB of RAM and Play refused to start after we brought the Wordpress site up on that machine, but then I added a swap file and everything worked sort of fine. Every once in a while Play application just stops with this weird Killed message on the console. No error messages precede this one, the log is clean before the termination. Application.log doesn't contain anything abnormal either. After that linux console glitches: enter does not create a prompt on the new line and pressing up does not bring previous command to the console, but pressing up followed by enter restarts an app.
I would really like to know the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's in your `/var/log/syslog`?  Sounds like the linux Out-of-Memory Killer to me.

Comment: Excerpts from syslog:    

`apache2 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0` 
...  
`Free swap  = 0kB`
...  
`Out of memory: Kill process 4508 (java) score 202 or sacrifice child`  
`Killed process 4508 (java) total-vm:3009564kB, anon-rss:281256kB, file-rss:0kB`
Thanks for help. Follow up question: why does apache invoke the out-of-memory killer? Can I lower apache's priority or make it fork less (process table in syslog contains about 40 instances of apache2)?